# How to connect galaxy tab with pc to run android app

Tags: android

Im trying to connect galaxy tab to my pc to run android app but it didn't recognize it in eclipse
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Turn `ADB Debugging` in the settings on your Galaxy Tab on and install the appropriate `ADB` drivers for your device (since I do not know your exact device, I can't provide you a link, but you should find them through Google pretty easily).

Comment: Thank you all ,,I downloaded it , but in my pc it work it can recognize it but in galxy it didn't recognize .. Nothing appear in my galaxy

Answer (score 0):

You will want to download [Samsung Kies](http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/) which contains the USB driver for Samsung devices.

Comment: Also, make sure to have done what @Leandros said about debugging